# Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I am using hp AMD Ryzen 7 4700U Radoen Graphics 2.00 GHz laptop. After sometime time windows 10 started throwing this error

Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

I tried many solutions but no success. i have updated all drivers with windows update, downloaded drivers from AMD website and installed them but no success. Laptop window is grayed out 1024*768

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can you please guide me to get out of this problem

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about this, but maybe, just maybe, your motherboard's firmware is incompatible with your graphics card, did you update your firmware?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall device and then restart your computer to see if it can install the latest driver automatically?

Comment: yes i tried uninstalling with amdcleanuputility.exe and the reinstall drivers again but no success